# Android Fade In Image

Tags: java, android, animation, fadein

I'm attempting to fade in an image using the same method as fading in text, but I'm getting the error "The method setAnimation(AlphaAnimation) is undefined for the type Image".

I've tried looking around some - I don't think I have to use an animation listener, as was the case in similar problems? I'm only trying to animate one image - here's the section of code:

```
    private void animateNinthDoctor() {
        AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1500);
        fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mImageView1.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    }
```

The error is given on the 'setAnimation' in the last line - mImageView1 is declared using

```
    private Image mImageView1;
```

Comment: can you post how do you declare `mImageView1`please?

Comment: `private Image mImageView1;`

Comment: Check this [android animation example](http://android.codota.com/scenarios/528e1e56da0acb4b08fd250c/android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation?tag=bumblebee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on the way you are defining the `mImageView1` variable. There is not an `Image` `Class` in Android; you should replace `Image` with `ImageView`.

Comment: I believe I'd had that earlier - when I define `mImageView1` with `ImageView`, I get the error "ImageView cannot be resolved to a type" on the `ImageView` in the declaration and on the `mImageView1` in the last line of the other section of code given.

Comment: you need to import `ImageView`. If you are using Eclipse press Ctrl+Shift+O to organize your imports.